# ¿Cómo puedo sumar y restar en la misma tabla y en otra diferente?

Tags: mysql, tablas

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta en la tabla `tblenvios` que sume y reste un valor dependiendo el estado, la fecha y el codigo del puntoAtencion, agrupada por codigo de puntoAtencion y a este resultado sumarle otra suma hecha en otra tabla `tblrecaudos` que sean iguales la fecha y codigo puntoAtencion.

Estas son las consultas que he realizado

```
CREATE TABLE tblenvios (
  idEnvio int(11) NOT NULL,
  valor double NOT NULL,
  fecha date NOT NULL,
  estado enum('1','2') NOT NULL,
  puntoA_E int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO tblenvios (idEnvio, valor, fecha, estado, puntoA_E) VALUES
(100001, 50000, '2019-03-18', '1', 8000),
(100002, 80000, '2019-03-18', '1', 8000),
(100003, 100000, '0000-00-00', '2', 8000),
(100004, 60000, '2019-03-18', '1', 8002);


CREATE TABLE tblpuntoatencion (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  codigo int(11) NOT NULL,
  barrio varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO tblpuntoatencion (id, codigo, barrio) VALUES
(1, 8000, 'Bosque'),
(2, 8001, 'Mercado'),
(3, 8002, 'Palmeras');


CREATE TABLE tblrecaudo (
  idRecaudo int(11) NOT NULL,
  valorRecaudo double NOT NULL,
  fecha date NOT NULL,
  puntoA int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO tblrecaudo (idRecaudo, valorRecaudo, fecha, puntoA) VALUES
(1, 30000, '2019-03-16', 8000),
(2, 20000, '2019-03-18', 8000),
(3, 40000, '2019-03-18', 8001);
```

tblPuntoAtencion

```
    id  codigo  barrio
    1   8000    bosque
    2   8001    mercado
    3   8002    palmeras
```

tblEnvios

```
    idEnvio   valor   fecha        estado  puntoA_E
    100001    50000   18-03-2019     1     8000
    100002    80000   18-03-2019     1     8000
    100003   100000   18-03-2019     2     8000
    100004    60000   18-03-2019     1     8002
```

tblrecaudo

```
    idrecaudo   valorRecaudo   fecha        puntoA
    1           30000          2019-03-16    8000
    2           20000          2019-03-18    8000
    3           40000          2019-03-18    8001
```

En la `tblEnvios` suma valor con estado 1 y por puntoA_E y fecha actual y le resta el valor con estado 2 por puntoA, fecha actual y se le suma valorRecaudo de la `tblrecaudo` por puntoA y fecha actual "suponiendo que la fecha actual es 2019-03-18"

Ejemplo:

```
codigo  valor     estado  -   codigo  valor     estado  +  puntoA   valorRecaudo  =  puntoA   total
8000    130000     1      -   8000    100000     2      +  8000     20000         =  8000     50000
```

resultados esperados

```
puntoA  total  fechaactual
8000    50000  2019-03-18
8001    40000  2019-03-18
8002    60000  2019-03-18
```

este es el resultados que me arroja

```
     puntoA_E   total   fecha
     8000       90000   2019-03-18
```

Con esta consulta me trae el resultado de la sumatoria de la `tblEnvios` y `tblrecaudo`
     pero faltaría algo porque no me arroja el dato exacto ayuda en esta parte

```
 SELECT puntoA_E,SUM(CASE WHEN E.puntoA_E = 8000 AND E.estado = 1 THEN E.valor ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN E.puntoA_E = 8000 AND E.estado = 2 THEN E.valor ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN R.puntoA = 8000 THEN R.valorRecaudo ELSE 0 END) AS total,E.fecha FROM tblenvios E,tblrecaudo R where E.puntoA_E=R.puntoA AND R.fecha ='2019-03-18' AND E.fecha ='2019-03-18' GROUP BY puntoA_E;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aporto otra solución más compacta:

```
SELECT punto,fecha,SUM(
    IF(estado=2,-valor,valor)
  ) total FROM (
    SELECT fecha,estado,puntoA_E punto,
      valor FROM tblenvios
    UNION
    SELECT fecha,3,puntoA punto,
      valorRecaudo valor FROM tblrecaudo  
  ) total
  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

La he obtenido juntando las dos tablas, asignándole el estado 3 a los registros de la tabla recaudo. Después ha sido agrupar y sumar teniendo en cuenta que los valores del estado 2 son negativos.

Espero que ambas soluciones te resulten útiles.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta solución:

```
SELECT punto,fecha,
  IFNULL(suma_envios,0)+
  IFNULL(suma_recaudo,0) total FROM (
    SELECT punto,fecha,suma_envios,suma_recaudo FROM (
        SELECT puntoA_E punto,fecha,SUM(
            IF(estado=1,valor,-valor)
          ) suma_envios FROM tblenvios
          GROUP BY 1,2
      ) envios LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT puntoA punto,fecha,
          SUM(valorRecaudo) suma_recaudo
          FROM tblrecaudo
          GROUP BY 1,2
      ) recaudos USING(punto,fecha)
    UNION
    SELECT punto,fecha,suma_envios,suma_recaudo FROM (
        SELECT puntoA_E punto,fecha,SUM(
            IF(estado=1,valor,-valor)
          ) suma_envios FROM tblenvios
          GROUP BY 1,2
      ) envios RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT puntoA punto,fecha,
          SUM(valorRecaudo) suma_recaudo
          FROM tblrecaudo
          GROUP BY 1,2
      ) recaudos USING(punto,fecha)  
  ) total
  ORDER BY punto,fecha;
```

En la tabla `tblenvios` de tu dataset tienes una fecha puesta a `0000-00-00`, la he modificado para que obtuvieras los resultados que esperabas.

Te comento un poco la solución:

- Realmente pedías un `FULL JOIN` y, en MySQL, esta operación aún no está implementada, así que he tenido que resolverla con un UNION de LEFT y RIGHT JOIN.
- Comentabas que necesitabas agrupar por punto y fecha, así que he puesto esos dos campos en el `GROUP BY`, resolviendo con un IF el tema del estado para hacer la operación SUM de totales.
- Tras unificar nombres de campos, sólo he tenido que conectar ambas soluciones intermedias
- La solución ya te calcula el dato para todas las fechas, si finalmente sólo quieres  una, admite un WHERE al final entre total y ORDER.

Si tienes cualquier duda, será un placer aclarártela.

Comment: David gracias por su pronta respuesta y funciona a la perfeccion, quiero preguntar que significa 1,2 en el group by

Comment: Que agrupe por los campos que aparecen en orden 1 y 2 tras el SELECT, así evito tener que volver a escribirlos :) [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

No puedes hacer join de las tablas, pues los resultados se duplicarán, triplicarán, etc. según la cantidad de registros que haya en las tablas.

Lo que usualmente se hace es hacer sub-consultas o CTE's que realicen las agrupaciones de manera individual en las tablas y al final se hace el join, ya con la seguridad que solo puede haber 1 registro de resumen por tabla.

Utilizando CTE's sería algo como:

```
with
Env as (
select   e.puntoA_E
       , e.Fecha
       , SUM(case 
               when e.Estado = 1 then e.Valor
               when e.Estado = 2 then e.Valor * -1
             end) TotalEnvios
  from tblEnvios e
 group by e.puntoA_E
        , e.Fecha
)
,
Rec as (
select   r.puntoA_E
       , r.Fecha
       , SUM(r.valorRecaudo) TotalRecaudo
  from tblRecaudo r
 group by r.puntoA_E
        , r.Fecha
)
select   Env.puntoA_E   
       , Env.Fecha
       , Env.TotalEnvios + coalesce(Rec.TotalRecaudo, 0) Total
  from Env
       left join Rec on Rec.puntoA_E = Env.puntoA_E and Rec.Fecha = Env.Fecha
```

Si cabe la posibilidad que haya un día en que hay Recaudos y no Envíos, el resultado sería incorrecto, puedes cambiar el `left join` por un `full outer join` y hacer los ajustes correspondientes en las columnas, para obtener el resultado correcto.

Un saludo.